# Scheme defining function

Tags: scheme, definition

I'm trying to come up with a way to add only positive integers up to a certain number in scheme and I can't for the life of me figure out a way to do it. I was trying to use recursion.

This is what i have so far:

```
(define sumEven
   (lambda(n)
        (cond((> n 0)1)
             ((even? n) (* (sumEven n (-(* 2 n) 1)
```

I was thinking the call would do something like:

```
 (sumEven N)=2 + 4 + ... + 2*N
```

and output something like this:

```
(sumEven 1)  ==> 2
(sumEven 4)  ==> 20
(sumEven 5)  ==> 30
```

but i'm not sure how to just add the even int and skip the odd. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
(define (sumEven n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (+ (* 2 n) (sumEven (- n 1)))))

(sumEven 1)
(sumEven 4)
(sumEven 5)

2
20
30
```

Comment: did not know it could be that simple,maybe i was over thinking it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can also implement the `sumEven` procedure by means of a [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) function, this has the advantage of reducing stack space requirements from linear, or O(n), to constant, or O(1). It's the recommended way to write a recursive procedure, whenever possible:

```
(define sumEven
  (lambda (n)
    (let loop ((n n)
               (acc 0))
      (cond ((zero? n)
             acc)
            (else
             (loop (sub1 n) (+ (* 2 n) acc)))))))
```

Yet another alternative, in tune with a more functional-programming style, would be to use list operations and [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) for creating a list with the numbers to be added, and then add them; for instance like this:

```
(define sumEven
  (lambda (n)
    (apply + (build-list (add1 n) (curry * 2)))))
```

Either way, the results are as expected:

```
(sumEven 1)
=> 2
(sumEven 4)
=> 20
(sumEven 5)
=> 30
```

Comment: thanks for the tip this will help me finish the program the i'am making